# Alternative to delayed job for simple cron task on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, background-process

In my Rails app on Heroku, I want to execute a simple block of code at 5 specific times in the future (each about a day apart), down to the second.

Is there a good way to do this without a background process?

I don't want to use Delayed Job because it'll require a Worker instance that costs ~$30/month. Seems unnecessary.

Is there a GOOD way to do this without Delayed Job / a Heroku Worker?

## Resolved

Thanks for your answers- looks like there isn't a solid way to accomplish this. Going with Delayed Job.

Answer (score 1):

use a rake task and heroku scheduler instead

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

> The scheduler add-on will run one-off processes that will count toward your dyno-hours for the month.

Comment: Unfortunately, 10 minutes is the shortest interval they offer, and they don't let you pick specific times. Also I think this is as expensive as a worker, at 5 cents an hour.

Comment: the cost is removed from your monthly dyno allowance (so, yes, it will cost you if your worker is already 100% used, otherwise will be free).  as in the doc `A dashboard allows you to configure jobs to run every 10 minutes, every hour, or every day, at a specified time.`, So you can pickup a specified time.

Comment: I saw that part about the specified time too- they actually mean you can run it at a particular time every day (can't pick very specific run times). And unfortunately its on the half hour. Looks like Delayed Job is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Rake task with the Heroku Scheduler, then add a bit of intelligent logic: `sleep until job_is_available if job_is_available_in_less_than_twelve_minutes?`

Then you're paying for the time to run the code, and the few seconds it takes your rake task to check if a job is available.  Something like 1-3 dollars, since Heroku pro-rates to the second.

Comment: That would work but `sleep` is unfortunately too much of a hack for this purpose. Looks like Delayed Job is the way to go.

Comment: no worries, you've gotta do what you've gotta do, but I'd love to hear more about why `sleep` is too hack-ish.  I can't see a business problem with it, it's horrible piece of duct tape from a theoretical standpoint, though?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with scheduler, you just need to check the day/hour etc when the task is running  - so you'd schedule an hourly job (if that will work for you) and then check the current day/hour to see if it's one that you want to run the job at and then run it inside the check. Not ideal but will work.

Comment: This would be nice, unfortunately it doesn't give me enough time granularity (need it down to the second).

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but...

Maybe it can solve your problems: [Sucker Punch](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch).

You don't need an extra dyno on Heroku. And it is possible to specify the time between the 5 blocks.